# Is there a way to prevent XOR encryption from becoming zero?

Tags: c

I want to encrypt data by XOR bit operation when socket communication

For example, if the key is "encrypt" and the data is "connect", then t will be 0 and the data will not be encrypted and decrypted correctly.
Also, if the data and key values are the same in the middle, it becomes 0 and ends the function as it is.
(data:connection, key:encrypt -> recv data is only connec)

How can I modify the function I used to eliminate this phenomenon?

```
char Encryption(char strEncordeData[])
{
    memset(m_socket_comm.encrypt, 0, BUF_SIZE);

    m_socket_comm.keycount = 0;
    int length = strlen(strEncordeData);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        m_socket_comm.encrypt[i] = strEncordeData[i] ^ m_socket_comm.key[m_socket_comm.keycount];
        if (m_socket_comm.keycount == strlen(m_socket_comm.key))
        {
            m_socket_comm.keycount = 0;
        }
        m_socket_comm.keycount++;
    }
    return *strEncordeData;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to be doing anything that treats text as raw bytes you need to move away from `strlen` and such and keep track of the actual length.

Comment: ... or use `std::string`, which interns that already.

Comment: either store the length separately, or do special treatment to avoid case resulting to `'\0'` (as keeping unchanged (for for encrypt and decrypt part)).

Comment: That algorithm is broken regardless. Assuming an initial `keycount` of zero, It uses every character *including* the terminator for the xor key rotation on the first loop only.  After that it starts at position 1 in the key and runs through the terminator for every subsequent sweep, never again revisiting the char at `key[0]`. I *strongly* suspect that is not intentional.

Comment: @WhozCraig I thought it would be enough to be in the `if (m_socket_comm.keycount == strlen(m_socket_comm.key))`

Comment: @RetiredNinja By the way, when I send and recv, it gives data as much as BUFSIZE (1024), so don't it encrypt everything if I strlen it?

Comment: @Jarod42 I have to try recv buffer length thanks!

Comment: @LieuRabbit you cannot use `strlen` if one of the bytes of your encrypted data becomes 0, because `strlen` on the encrypted string then consders that the string ends at that 0.

Comment: @LieuRabbit That `if` block, including reset to zero, belongs *above* the xor assignment; not below. Read your code again and explain it to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The question's tagged `c`.

Comment: @ray [meanwhile](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73398157/timeline#history_3a71ceed-1131-4ee8-8c55-a881010a6218), yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `strlen` does is search for the `\0`, so why not write your own version that checks if the byte is `\0` *after* decryption? (Note that this requires encrypting the `\0` terminator):

```
size_t cipherlen(const char *ciphertext, const char *key) {
    size_t idx, keylen = strlen(key);
    for (idx = 0; 1; idx++) {
        if (0 == (ciphertext[idx] ^ key[idx % keylen])) break;
    }
    return idx;
}
```

Or better yet, don't even bother with strlen. Just keep decrypting until you hit the `\0`:

```
// encrypt in place
void encrypt(char *s, const char *key) {
    size_t keylen = strlen(key);
    for (size_t idx = 0; 1; idx++) {
        // We encrypt the \0 before terminating the loop
        char c = s[idx];
        s[idx] ^= key[idx % keylen];
        if (!c) break;
    }
}

// decrypt in place
void decrypt(char *s, const char *key) {
    /* Note that we compute strlen(key) *once* instead of recalculating
       it every iteration. Doing it the other way requires repeatedly
       scanning over the full key and turns an O(n) algorithm into O(n)O(m).
    */
    size_t keylen = strlen(key);
    for (size_t idx = 0; 1; idx++) {
        s[idx] ^= key[idx % keylen];
        if ('\0' == s[idx]) break;// We check the value *after* decryption.
    }
}
```

Although personally, I'd store the plaintext and key lengths separately rather than using strlen, so as to permit arrays of char that contain `\0`.

Comment: I have to send data and length too thanks!